# G++ Compile and Run Without Output

Tags: compile, c++, g++

This is just a convenience thing. Is there a way to use C++ sort of like an interpreted language, only in the sense that you could compile and run it without outputting a binary file. This is of course assuming it's a single c++ that doesn't need any other libraries to run.

I'm just wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output to a temporary file (e.g. in /tmp) which you remove afterwards, or leave it and overwrite the next time.

You may be interested in [IGCC](http://www.artificialworlds.net/wiki/IGCC/IGCC).

Comment: yeah. IGCC is the way to go.